# Sharing a Model among pages (views) in a Metro Style App

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, singleton, microsoft-metro

I have a Metro app consisting of several pages, all deriving from **LayoutAwarePage**. I've implemented navigation to and back from them. This works like a charm. What I want to do now is to share common data between these views like for example:

- access to a model, let's Name it **MyModel**
- an instance of a controller, let's name it **MyController**
- common business logic, let's name it **MyLogic**

In the past I was used to "inject" those dependencies via constructor. This is now not possible anymore (right?). How can I do this otherwise keeping in mind that I want to avoid:

- singletons (because of testing)
- public static properties (which is similar to singletons)

Is it ok to pass kind of a context object to the Frame.Navigate() method? Does anybody have a good advice?

P.S. I want to avoid using Frameworks like MVVM light or Cocoon.

Cheerio!

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't inject dependencies via constructor? What's preventing you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something very simple.  If that is the case, I would just add a property to App.xaml.cs.

You set/get that property from anywhere in your application with something like (App.Current as App).MyProperty.  Very brute force but it works.

I have also seen the same approach but with a master container assigned to App.xaml.cs property, then an extension method with a getContainer() method - just to reduce the number of times you have to write (App.Current as App).

Comment: As mentioned above, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like a neat way to access my controller/model/logic from every view **without** exposing them as public static variables or singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I found a good solution for me [1]. It's still not exactly what I was looking for, because it's using the MVVM light toolkit and its Messenger concept - but it's clean.

[1] http://forums.silverlight.net/p/200771/468507.aspx

Comment: http://slickthought.net/post/2011/04/26/Message-Based-Navigation-for-WP7-MVVM-Apps.aspx if you do not want to bite off all of MVVMLight.  The Messenger concept is nice if you are interested in sharing info between views on a single page.  But if, which seems like the case based on your description, you are passing data between pages which happen to contain a view, not sure what this buys you vs. a property off of App.